# django-south installation

Tags: django-south

Hi am trying to install south and set it up to work with my current django app but when i install it and run syncdb i gat the following errors what can i do to it?

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 185, in inner  return func(self._wrapped, *args) AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'DATABASE_ENGINE'
```

i do have a data base running and am using django 1.4 and the south am instaling is the most recently installed.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you haven't configured the DATABASE_ENGINE in settings.py (maybe it's commented out or something).